# Copy a FITS header

Tags: python, python-3.x, astropy

Say I read a FITS file

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename

image_file = get_pkg_data_filename('tutorials/FITS-images/HorseHead.fits')
cube = fits.open(image_file)[0]
```

And I want to make a copy of its header so I can modify the copy without changing the original header

```
header_copy = cube.header
header_copy.remove('OBJCTY')
```

However, this also modifies `cube.header`.

How would I go about to make an actual copy of the header, rather than creating a new pointer to the header?

`header_copy = ?`

Comment: Perhaps the [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) module? `import copy` then `header_copy = copy.copy(cube.header)`

Comment: Indeed, `copy` seems to do what I expect. I was rather stumped by the fact that the behaviour of cube.header and cube.data are not the same when I tried to copy them, but the answer turned out to be quite simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Header` class from `astropy.io.fits` has a [copy function](https://astropy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/io/fits/api/headers.html#astropy.io.fits.Header.copy).

```
header_copy = cube.header.copy()
header_copy.remove('OBJCTY')
```

Then `header_copy` is an actual copy of the object, rather than a pointer towards `cube.header`

```
if cube.header['OBJECTY'] != header_copy['OBJECTY']:
    print('All ok')

>>> All ok
```